# Swift unrecognized selector sent to instance - MTLRenderPipelineColorAttachment?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, metal

Alright, Im working in ARkit here in Swift and I have no idea what is causing this crash - something with metal, but Google/Stack isn't being helpful here. Error is:

```
[MTLRenderPipelineColorAttachmentDescriptorArrayInternal baseObject]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c4694eb0
2018-02-15 13:52:25.185620-0800 LittleBot[43374:20799014] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MTLRenderPipelineColorAttachmentDescriptorArrayInternal baseObject]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c4694eb0'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Just navigating my SCNNode in SceneKit through space. Nothing big, but error isn't drawn on any specific function, so I don't know what to do here -

[image]

What could cause this/what should I check in scene kit here?

Any problematic code:

```
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
            updateFocusSquare()
            if let lightEstimate = session.currentFrame?.lightEstimate {
                //print("light: ", lightEstimate)
                //sceneView.scene.lightingEnvironment.intensity = 4000
                 sceneView.scene.enableEnvironmentMapWithIntensity(1000, queue: serialQueue)

            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let center = self.view.center
                guard let realWorldPosition = self.sceneView.realWorldPosition(for: center) else { return }
                sceneCenterPt = realWorldPosition

            }

            //DUDE MOVEMENT -------------------

            theDude.updateVars()
            if previousUpdateTime == 0.0 {
                previousUpdateTime = time
            }

            let deltaTime = time - previousUpdateTime
            let characterSpeed = CGFloat(deltaTime) * 2.0 * theDude.walkSpeed

            let direction = theDude.characterDirection(withPointOfView: renderer.pointOfView)

            print(theDude.characterDirection(withPointOfView: theDude.node))
            //print(theDude.directionAngle)


            // move
            if !direction.allZero() {
                theDude.characterVelocity = direction * Float(characterSpeed)
                var runModifier = Float(1.0)
                theDude.walkSpeed = CGFloat(runModifier * simd_length(direction))

                // move character - IMPORTANT
                theDude.directionAngle = CGFloat(atan2f(direction.x, direction.z))

                theDude.node.runAction(SCNAction.move(by: SCNVector3(theDude.characterVelocity), duration: TimeInterval(350)))
                print(theDude.walkSpeed)

               theDude.isWalking = true
            } else {
                theDude.isWalking = false
                theDude.node.removeAllActions()
            }

func loadNode (hitPos: SCNVector3, theScene: ARSCNView) {

        for child in modelScene.rootNode.childNodes {
            node.addChildNode(child) //child is actually in scene visible, node is container

//            if(child.name == childNodeIDShouldBe)
//            {
//                childNode = child
//            }
        }


         //good pos : SCNVector3(x: 0.0453629047, y: -0.19758147, z: -0.449025244)
        node.position = hitPos

        //SETUP ---------------------------------------
        setupCharPhysics()


        getMaterials()
        //setTraits()
        setMaterial(name: "baseMat") //first mat
        //-------------------------------------

        theScene.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
        print(self.node.name, "| ", self.node.parent)


        //https://blog.pusher.com/animating-3d-model-ar-arkit-mixamo/
        //**ids go: [NAME_OF_FILE]-1
        //load all animations :

        for (a,key) in animScenes {

            loadAnimation(withKey: key, sceneName: a, animationIdentifier: "\(URL(string: a)?.lastPathComponent)-1")
        }

    }
```

Comment: If you’re working entirely with SceneKit, any error coming from Metal API is presumably a bug. [Filing one with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com) is probably your best recourse.

Comment: Looks familiar but not sure if it’s the same. Are you updating a SCNGeometry or SCNGeometrySource of a node that is being rendered? If so, either use a tripple buffer system as described by Apple or simply set the playing property of the sceneview to false before you update it, and turn it back on after the update.

Comment: @Xartec im a little new to this, but I am doing something with physics body shapes.. could you expand on what that means -updating a SCNGeometry?

Comment: Accidentally hit Enter while typing my comment.

Comment: Can you post the portion of the code that is likely causes the crash?

Comment: @Xartec done, in question

Comment: I’m not able to reproduce the error in my own nor your code. I wonder if this was a big that has been fixed in 11.3 beta which I am using. Do you get the error consistently? If so, try to comment lines/parts of the code to track down where exactly the problem is. Such as the async part, the set materials part and the animation loading at the end. If you are not on 11.3 beta, you may want to try that before possibly chasing down a bug in Apple’s code.

Comment: @Xartec It isn't consistent, thats my issue - only sometimes. Guess I should wait for beta?